# Is is possible to make Highcharts stacked column skip empty date values?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is is possible to make Highcharts skip empty date values?

I have a stacked column chart with amounts on the Y axis and dates on the X axis. But the dates are very much spread making the chart extremely wide if all values are to be seen clearly.

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/8j1ar44L/13/

If all values are in 2016 it looks nice, but to demonstrate the problem I changed the last dataset to 2017. In the real use case, it is actually much worse as we span several years.

Setting [ordinal](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.ordinal) true doesn't work:

```
xAxis: {
        type: "datetime",
        tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
        ordinal: true
    },
```

How can I make Highcharts simply ignore missing dates and thus ignore white space between the columns?

Comment: *ordinal: true* is a **Highstock** property, not available in Highcharts. There is no way have dates specified in the x values, and also have those x values ignored. If you want your data points to always be sequential, regardless of how much time is between them, use categories instead.

Comment: @jlbriggs: The empty dates are actually not specified in the x values, it is Highcharts that interpolates these dates.

Comment: Re. categories, how can I add dates that show up as dates but really are categories?

Comment: No, the chart is plotting what you have told it to plot - it is not interpolating anything. You provide x values, so the chart plots the data on the x values that you have provided. As it should.

Comment: I don't generally recommend using categories for dates. But, I don't see another way to do what you're asking (other than using **Highstock**).  You will need to process your data, and send the date, as a string, to the **categories** array. Don't specify x values in your data, and they will be plotted in order.

Comment: example:  http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/8j1ar44L/15/

Comment: What I mean is that I haven't inserted any values for eg. August 2015 but the chart still renders these dates for which there are no data. I guess we are just misunderstanding each other.

Comment: The chart renders an axis that goes from the start to the end, and places tick marks along it. It is not rendering anything specific to the dates that you haven't provided. Again - it's plotting exactly what you've told it to, in the way that you've told it to. That's key to understanding how to work with it.

Comment: I used you last fiddle as a base for modifying my code. I had to write some JS code that transformed the series data into data acceptable for category based date values. It works like a charm.